# Type is inferred differently in a lexical binding in GHCi

Tags: haskell, type-inference, ghci

Greeting,

I am a little surprised that I get two different type in GHCi with the same expression whether I bind it or not. I defined a function to print Tree in a user friendly format with the drawTree with this

```
let printTree = putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show
```

The inferred type is `Show a => Tree () -> IO ()`. This is not what I was expected. So I tried to type directly the body of `printTree`. Indeed, this gave me the expected type

```
putStrLn . drawTree . fmap show :: Show a => Tree a -> IO ()
```

I know that I can define `printTree` with `$` or with a parameter to avoid this problem. However, I wonder why GHCi doesn't get the same type.

Can someone explain me this behavior ? 
Thank you

Comment: What's the type of `drawTree`?

Comment: You sort of have to read everything in the linked duplicate question to get the whole story, but the answer is GHCi 7.6's extended defaulting rules (which extend haskell's numeric defaulting rules), combined with the monomorphism restriction. GHCi 7.8 exhibits the more polymorphic behavior

Comment: ok so, this is still a monomorphism problem. Thank you ;)